# regex php expression works in test but not in practice

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a regex in [Rad Soft](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner) to pull out a div tag from some html. It tested well in the editor and [php regex tester](http://www.mytechnologycenter.com/tech/regex-tester-php.php).  Now I am trying to get it to implement with php on my current project but just doesn't work. Usually its some simple solution that is failing to register since I have been staring at the problem too long.

here is the test sample being used

```
$temp = '<div>blah blah blah.
    You ordered these items: 
    <div id="product_list">

 - 1  Large -  Target
<span class="pricedisplay">R$ 1,00</span>
- 1  Large - Black
<span class="pricedisplay">R$ 1,00</span>
- 1  Large - Leather
<span class="pricedisplay">R$ 1,00</span>
- 1  Large - Preto
<span class="pricedisplay">R$ 1,00</span>

</div><span class="total-shipping"></span><span class="total-price">Total: <span class="pricedisplay">R$ 1,00</span>
</span></div>';
```

and for the regex:

```
<div\sid="product_list">([\s\w\d<=>/\\\$:",\.-]?)*[^(</div>)]</div>
```

which I tried using here:

```
$outputHTML = preg_replace_callback(preg_quote('<div\sid="product_list">([\s\w\d<=>/\\\$:",\.-]?)*[^(</div>)]</div>'), 'findProducts', $temp);
```

I have tried with/without the preg_quote. And if you know of any software similar to Rad that better simulates php's regex, it would help alot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why are you parsing HTML with regex?!?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/540162)

Comment: _"I wrote a regex in Rad Soft to pull out a div tag from some html."_ That was your first mistake.

Comment: @Nightfirecar a certain module in WP passes data simular to this to be presented but has little or no markup except <p>. Short of trying to rewrite parts of the plugin, hence making it un-upgradible in the future.

Comment: @Herbert, Would you suggest a better way to go about using/modeling regex?

Comment: @Nightfirecat I can see as FailedDev points out this was the wrong strategy for this problem.

Comment: @samuel.molinski: My apologies. I wasn't referring to Rad Soft. I was referring to using regex to _pull out a div tag from some html_. I would suggest using the [PHP DOM classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). It's a far less error prone way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether this regex happened to work with some tester there are many mistakes in it.

First :

```
[\s\w\d<=>/\\\$:",\.-]
```

Equals too :

```
[\s\w\d<=>/$:",.\\-]
```

You need not unescape characters inside character class. Additionally you use preg_quote which escapes : `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Secondly :

```
[^(</div>)]
```

Means :

```
"
[^(</div>)]    # Match a single character NOT present in the list “(</div>)”
"
```

While what you probably wanted to write is :

```
(?<!</div>)

"
(?<!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   </div>       # Match the characters “</div>” literally
)
"
```

Lastly :

`([\s\w\d<=>/\\\$:",\.-]?)*` **equals** : `[\s\w\d<=>/$:",.\\-]*`

Oh and yeah, what you are doing is potentially dangerous. You shouldn't try to extract/parse html/xml/xhtml with regex when you have ready to use tools in your language.

Comment: I was obviously total oblivious to the tools already existing inside of php, my mistake. I also see that I need a lot more work on creating regex. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

PHP regex should have delimiter like this:

- `/hello/` the delimiter is / here
- `#<div\sid="\w+">([^<]+)</div>#` the delimiter is #

You could use any char you want, you just have to be careful that you delimiter is not present in the regex itself, or you should have to escape it. In some case, it's better to switch to another delimiter, such as in the second example where the `/` char is in use in `</div>`.

I've not looked deep into your regex, but you could try to:

- reduce the text to test, removing some parts and then test again it, to locate which part may cause a problem
- reduce the regex, for the same reasons,

<del>Also, your text is multi-line, you should put a [pattern modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).</del> See comment from Alan below

Comment: Good catch on the delimiters, but he doesn't need to use any modifiers.  It's not what's in the *text* that determines the need for modifiers, it's what's in the regex.  There are no `^` or `$` anchors, so the `m` flag would have no effect, and he isn't using `.` to match newlines, so `s` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add appropriate delimiters around the regex, e.g.

```
$outputHTML = preg_replace_callback(
    '#<div\sid="product_list">([\s\w\d<=>/\\\$:",\.-]?)*[^(</div>)]</div>#', 
    'findProducts', 
    $temp);
```

In the example `#` is the delimiter that marks the beginning and end of the regular expression. It's required so PHP can determine if there are any modifiers after the regex (e.g. `#<some regex here>#i` where `i` is a modifier). See [Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: +1. The way he has it now, the first `<` and the last `>` are being interpreted as regex delimiters.  Otherwise he'd be getting compilation errors.

Comment: Really? I'm not convinced of that. He just says it "just doesn't work" - maybe it's not working because it's failing to compile, and he's not seeing warnings because they're suppressed. I tried it just with `<` and `>` and got a warning, at least. `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('`, so I assume it'd be ending the regex at the first `>`, and taking `(` as a modifier, rather than ending it at the last `>`. Probably a risky strategy when matching against HTML, anyway.

Comment: The first char in the regex is always interpreted as a delimiter D. Then, the next times the interpreter encounters the same char D, and if it's not escaped, then it consider it has reach the end of the regex. Then every chars after that char D is interpreted as a modifier, that's why you get that error.
The interpreter can't use the first *and last* chars as delimiter automatically, because if it does, how can he know if the regex has modifiers ? Modifiers should appears after the delimiter, but the interpreter considers the last char is a delimiter... I think that can't work ^^

Comment: Yep, my bad.  I jumped to a conclusion about what the OP meant by "it doesn't work".